# How can geometry_msgs::Point use push_back()?

Tags: rviz, ros-kinetic, ubuntu, geometry-msgs, ubuntu-xenial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, guys.

I'm trying to study rviz with tutorials provided by [ros wiki](http://wiki.ros.org/rviz/Tutorials/Markers%3A%20Points%20and%20Lines).
I built a sample of document using catkin_make, saw the result.

On the line of this sample codes,

```
...
visualization_msgs::Marker points, line_strip, line_list;
...
for(ellipsis) {
    ...
    geometry_msgs::Point p;
    p.x = (int32_t)i - 50;
    p.y = y;
    p.z = z;

    points.points.push_back(p);
    ...
}
...
```

**How can the variable of geometry_msgs::Point type use push_back()?**

I saw it's msg header on [the link](http://docs.ros.org/api/geometry_msgs/html/msg/Point.html)
It is just msg consist of 3 variables of `float64` type.
The function, push_back(), It appears to be used like push_back of stl.

Could you tell me how this works?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/290292/how-can-geometry_msgs::point-use-push_back()?/) by [harderthan](https://answers.ros.org/users/34798/harderthan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 98 on 2018-05-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[visualization_msgs/Marker](http://docs.ros.org/api/visualization_msgs/html/msg/Marker.html) contains a `points` field, which is of type `geometry_msgs/Point[]`. That is an unbounded array (== list) of [geometry_msgs/Point](http://docs.ros.org/api/geometry_msgs/html/msg/Point.html)s.

Lists in the ROS msg IDL are mapped to `std::vector`s for C++ (see [wiki/msg - Message Description Specification - Array handling](http://wiki.ros.org/msg#Message_Description_Specification)).

And `std::vector` has a `push_back(..)` method that in this case will take `geometry_msgs/Point`.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-05-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [harderthan](https://answers.ros.org/users/34798/harderthan/) on 2018-05-14**:
Thank you.